# How to differentiate between commas in excel's cells vs commas in CSV

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

My application's data is often prepared in excel before I save it as a CSV and it is read in my app. I am currently using [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14254/Converting-CSV-Data-to-Objects) to import my CSV file and convert it to object data.

For some reason, excel is able to differentiate between commas contained in each cell vs commas separating the cells, but when I use the CSV reader (which splits it by ","), it is not able to differentiate the two.

Using C#, is there some way I can tell which is an actual comma vs which is a new cell in the CSV file?

Below is a sample in excel. It is saved as a "CSV Comma delimited" and has no problem opening in excel but separated Column3 into "Some" and "thing", thinking it's 2 separate columns.

[image]

Comment: can you supply some CSV and excel sample data?

Comment: There are several CSV helper libs.  MS's TextFieldParser is one.  If the cell/field data is not quoted (`"foo", "bar", "1,000"...`) you may be screwed.  FileHelper is another

Comment: @pnuts I think Excel and Access both do, but he says it is `*often* prepared in excel`, I have no idea what the others would look like.

Comment: Another way to avoid `String.Split` is to use OleDB to import the data to a DataTable.  You can define the columns and let it do type conversions (supply you with `Integer`s and `Date`s rather than string data).

Comment: no, show a sample of the CSV **data** you are reading, not a picture of excel

Comment: @Plutonix, I thought you meant upload and I didn't know how.

Comment: @pnuts I just realized excel does add quotation marks when there is a comma inserted in the cell.

Comment: it should wrap *each* cell in commas; the problem is that String.Split is too crude for splitting that kind of CSV - it doesnt treat ones inside quotes as "protected".  You need one of the smarter libs or OleDb  (with which you could import directly from XL).

Comment: @Plutonix would it not be a good idea to iterate through the split string and try to recombine ones with quotations? Or would that hinder performance?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at RFC 4180 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180 this is a standard for CSV files that is fairly common, and Excel files generated will conform to this (i have heard there is an exception relating to headings being missing, but haven't come across this).
Note: Although Excel works well with 4180, SSIS doen't follow it (although will read ok), and there are other exceptions across the microsoft suite.

Excel creates CSV records with quotes (") around the field if it contains a comma, so your parser needs to treat anything in quotes as data not a field delimiter.

You can easily view CSVs created in Excel by right clicking the file and choose edit, should open in Notepad.

Sample Records (from an address verification application):

```
aa001,1 Devon Court Nar Nar Goon Vic 3823 Australia
aa002,"471 Princes Drive, Sale Vic 3916 Australia"

aa001 - Excel puts no quotes around field, as doen't contain comma
aa002 - Excel puts quotes around field as it contains comma
```

I'm not aware of any parser in C#, looked a few years ago and gave up and had a programmer build based on rfc4180 (I don't have the code).

Apache have a parser in Java you can download the source from https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi to look at.